# XAMPP MySQL will not start on Mac Mavericks Version 10.9.3

Tags: mysql, macos

I am trying to run MySQL through XAMPP on Mac Version 10.9.3.

When I try to run it i get

[image]

But after about 30 seconds it reverts to this

[image]

Here is the XAMPP application log:
[image]

I've looked into whether or not port 3306 is being used but it seems like its not being used:

```
Last login: Wed May 28 19:10:04 on ttys000
John-MacBook-Air:~ John$ lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
SpotifyWe 230 John    6u  IPv4 0x1a81be5beea7cc07      0t0  TCP localhost:4370 (LISTEN)
SpotifyWe 230 John    7u  IPv4 0x1a81be5beea7c41f      0t0  TCP localhost:4380 (LISTEN)
Dropbox   233 John   28u  IPv4 0x1a81be5be15b041f      0t0  TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)
Dropbox   233 John   38u  IPv4 0x1a81be5be1606c07      0t0  TCP localhost:26164 (LISTEN)
```

Can somebody spot the problem?

EDIT: I've run this several times over the past week and it has worked.
EDIT: Starting apache first doesn't fix the problem.
EDIT: log url https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz9zqt55mbd219m/log

Comment: you need to start apache first. mysql can be started without the apache web server. you need a server to run your db on

Comment: I've tried that multiple times, same issue.

Comment: try it, if that works i´ll put it as an aswer so you can mark it as answered

Comment: what errors do you get when apache is running?

Comment: as for windows(dunno if that can happen on a mac as well but i guess so) skype blocked my mysql service once. if you have skype installed, log out and close skype then try it again.

Comment: Nothing comes in the application log and there are no error messages that pop up.  Literally i hit start, it says "starting" for thirty seconds and then just goes back to "stopped" in a instant.

Comment: I do have skype installed BUT skype is not running.  I've done this several times before, the mySQL server just suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Try with sudo: sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=mysql

Comment: It could also be a problem with chown. If you had mysql before and installed xampp after maybe the rights are not configured properly or maybe xampp doesn't have the rights to start mysql.

Comment: No i'm using XAMPP's provied SQL

Comment: This post was written back in May. How did you end up fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to me several times over the course of a few months.

I've found that you need to do the following:

1. Quit XAMPP
2. Open activity monitor ( basically task manager for mac )
3. Navigate to CPU tab
4. Find process "mysqld" and kill it ( click on it and click x in top left hand corner )

This has been working for me so far.  Will update if any further solutions become available.